# Scala-like Flatten from command line

Tags: linux, scala, awk, sed

Given a file like this:

```
foo,1,2,3
bar,2,3,4
too,6,2,3
```

Is it possible to produce this from command line:

```
foo,1,0
foo,2,1
foo,3,2
bar,2,0
bar,3,1
bar,4,2
too,6,0
too,2,1
too,3,2
```

Comment: You should show some research effort: what have you tried, what didn't work, what is the concrete problem. See http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score 0):

When asking how to transform data in one form to data in another form it is generally better to be very explicit about what exactly the transformation consists of.  In this case it seems obvious, but who knows?

This --

```
 awk -F, 'BEGIN{OFS=","}{print $1,$2,0;print $1,$3,1;print $1,$4,2;}' ORIGINAL_FILE.dat
```

-- will give the transformation you show.  It assumes your input data is always in exactly 4 rows.  You don't say, so who knows?  It assumes a particular transformation, but others might be possible -- i.e., it assumes that the third column in the output is the zero-indexed number of the column of the previous item in the input data, not counting the first column.

Answer (score 0):

`awk` to the rescue!

```
$ awk 'BEGIN{FS=OFS=","} 
            {for(i=2;i<=NF;i++) print $1,$i,c[$1]++}' file

foo,1,0
foo,2,1
foo,3,2
bar,2,0
bar,3,1
bar,4,2
too,6,0
too,2,1
too,3,2
```